# Ruby GC::Profiler "Use Size" is greater than "Total Size"

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

I'm trying to slim down a part of my application, so I'm using the GC::Profiler to tell whether this or that does actually slim down anything, but I'm getting a result I can't interpret:

```
Index    Invoke Time(sec)       Use Size(byte)     Total Size(byte)         Total Object                    GC Time(ms)
1               2.409             13943640             15840440               396011        36.48399999999973886133
.
.
102             7.074             30720080             30525000               763125        30.90900000000029734792
103             7.359             31267800             30525000               763125        34.99699999999972277465
.
.
1664          461.066            739610760             30525000               763125        32.36799999996264887159
```

According to the docs, this would seem to say that more than 2000% of the allocated heap is currently used...? And would indicate that my memory usage is growing, except that the total heap size apparently isn't...

My task is: I'm reading a large incoming HTTP stream directly to a file, and then reading the file one line at a time via lazy evaluation, performing a transform on each line, and writing it out to a file.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Edit: Ruby 2.0 on a Mac

Edit 2: `ps aux` reports 2936436 VSS and 455836 RSS